# How to skip a particular script from execution in flyway

Tags: flyway

I have merged some code in git repository with three scripts(V1,V2,V3) for Flyway), and I have later found out that there is a problem in the script (V2). I don't want to modify the script V2, I just want to skip the execution of the script V2 by Flyway.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution would be to change the sql file name so that it is not taken into account anymore by Flyway (Eg. V2_scriptname -> OLD_V2_scriptname). That should do it if changing the sql file name is an option.